# How to access the Result Set value outside the block in java?

Tags: java, mysql, email

I have a MySQL database which has user details like name,password,email,address etc.
I could access them with usual `Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)` and so on.

```
String sql="select * from customer where name="+user"";

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
String email=rs.getString("email");
}
```

Now I need this email data for sending email to respective user and so I accessed his email like this.I used this code(JavaMail) for sending mail to the user's email.

```
 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(email));
```

My problem is  I can't access this email variable outside the while block.It shows error as ***email variable is not defined***.
Any help pls...

Comment: Please Google *variable scope*

Comment: So declare email within the scope it is needed, not super locally as you're doing.